# Spring integration: sftp-inbound-adapter with retry

Tags: spring-integration

I implemented a sftp-inbound-adapter which should be launched every day at 2PM and I like doing only one  retry after 2 hours  if the result is empty (no files received),

How can i do this using the retry mechanism?
My source code is the following:

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
    auto-startup="true" channel="receiveChannel" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
    local-directory="file:local-dir" remote-directory="/"
    auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="false"
    filename-regex=".*\.txt$">

    <int:poller cron="0 0 14 * * ?"></int:poller>

    <int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <ref bean="retryAdvice" />
    </int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>

</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with 4.2, you can use a [Smart Poller](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#__smart_polling) to adjust the poll frequency based on whether there was a message or not.

Out of the box, there's the `SimpleActiveIdleMessageSourceAdvice` which uses a different fixed-delay (via a `DynamicPeriodicTrigger`) when there's a message Vs. no message.

If you don't like it's algorithm (it uses delays, not a cron expression), you can write a custom subclass of `AbstractMessageSourceAdvice`.

I am not sure what your `retryAdvice` bean is, but retry usually only applies if there was an exception.

**EDIT**

I have created a new advice that's more suitable for you; see [the gist here](https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/f2f465ec7e9780db415f).

You would configure it like this...

```
...
    <int:poller trigger="compoundTrigger">
        <int:advice-chain>
            <bean class="example.CompoundTriggerAdvice">
                <constructor-arg ref="compoundTrigger"/>
                <constructor-arg ref="secondary"/>
            </bean>
        </int:advice-chain>
    </int:poller>
...

<bean id="compoundTrigger" class="example.CompoundTrigger">
    <constructor-arg ref="primary" />
</bean>

<bean id="primary" class="org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger">
    <constructor-arg value="0 0 14 * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean id="secondary" class="org.springframework.scheduling.support.PeriodicTrigger">
    <constructor-arg value="7200000" />
</bean>
```

When no message is received, we'll use the secondary trigger (2 hours), otherwise, the cron trigger.

Comment: thnak you Gary. But I like implementing SimpleActiveIdleMessageSourceAdvice but no samples available on the internet. can you give me a samole if its use ?